# PyTorch C++ is slow on Ubuntu aarch64

Tags: pytorch, arm64

I'm trying to compare Windows x64 and Ubuntu aarch64 of our code, that uses PyTorch C++ 1.5.1.

When most of the process in our code is running from same speed to twice faster on Ubuntu than on Windows, all calls to PyTorch are running 3 times slower.

I try to find any information on PyTorch for arm64, if it has been as optimized as on x64? As there is no MKL, pytorch goes with eigen and openblas. Is it a reason for this slowdown?

Thank you,

Gérald

Comment: Yes, by default, PyTorch for aarch64 uses BLAS (openBLAS) backend. How many cores are you exercising for your application? Are you building the OpenBLAS and PyTorch locally? or are you using the wheel from PyTorch org? Regards,
SN.

Comment: I tried to build it locally, and I tried with anaconda, but I get same results.
And I think by default we configure it to use 1 core (on Windows or Linux). I'll double check that part.